(q/kdb+) How do I separate a list into a list of lists at certain indexes
I have indexes of data below but it is all now in one list and I need to separate it into a list of lists.
q)rowsOfDataIndexes
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22
25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38
41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57
60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88
91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121
124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139
142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152
155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168
171 172 173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62
65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82
85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96
99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114
117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13
16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42
45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61
64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93
96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29
32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60
63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76
79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106
109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123
126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140
143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16
19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45
48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83
86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106
109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125
128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143
146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156
159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172
175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34
37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52
55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68 69 70 71
74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90
93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107
110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131
134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151
154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170
173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187
190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197 198 199 200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207
210 211 212 213 214 215 216 217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224
227 228 229 230 231 232 233 234 235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242
245 246 247 248 249 250 251 252 253 254 255 256 257 258
261 262 263 264 265 266 267 268 269 270 271 272 273 274 275 276 277
280 281 282 283 284 285 286 287 288 289 290 291 292 293 294
297 298 299 300 301 302 303 304 305 306 307 308 309 310 311 312 313 314
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17
20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66 67 68
71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97
100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112
115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123 124 125 126 127 128 129
132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146
149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161
164 165 166 167 168 169 170 171 172 173 174 175 176 177
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31
34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47
50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64 65 66
69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82
85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106
109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122 123
126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144
147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155 156 157 158 159 160 161 162
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35 36 37 38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48
51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77 78 79 80 81 82
85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98
101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108 109 110 111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121 122
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30 31 32 33 34 35
38 39 40 41 42 43 44 45 46 47 48 49 50 51 52 53 54 55 56 57 58 59 60 61 62 63 64
67 68 69 70 71 72 73 74 75 76 77
80 81 82 83 84 85 86 87 88 89 90 91 92 93 94 95 96 97 98 99 100 101 102 103 104 105 106 107 108
111 112 113 114 115 116 117 118 119 120 121
124 125 126 127 128 129 130 131 132 133 134 135 136 137 138 139 140 141 142 143 144 145 146 147 148 149 150 151 152 153 154 155
158 159 160 161 162 163 164 165 166 167 168 169 170
173 174 175 176 177 178 179 180 181 182 183 184 185 186 187 188 189 190 191 192 193 194 195 196 197
200 201 202 203 204 205 206 207 208 209 210 211 212 213 214
217 218 219 220 221 222 223 224 225 226 227 228 229 230 231 232
235 236 237 238 239 240 241 242 243 244 245 246

Below is the count of how many of the lines in list above belong to each row so the first 9 lines is data in row 1 and the 7 lines after those 9 lines is data inn row 2 and so on.
q)countOfIndexPairs
9 7 7 10 11 17 9 8 6 11
q)

How would I do this? I have tried iterating through the # function but not sure if there is a common practice approach for a situation like this?

One way to do this is with the cut operator _.
You need to append 0 to countOfIndexPairs and cut using the running sum (sums):
-1 _ sums[0,countOfIndexPairs] _ rowsOfDataIndexes

This should work for the case where the sum of the row counts is less than the count of rowsOfDataIndexes. The -1 _ ensures the last group of rows is dropped which in this case contains 0 rows.
Assuming you want to collapse each of these into lists then you just need to raze each separately.
raze each -1 _ sums[0,countOfIndexPairs] _ rowsOfDataIndexes


You can use cut to achieve what you're after. This takes a list of integers and a list or table and cuts it into sub-arrays. Although it requires a non-decreasing list of integers of indexes as the first argument so you can use sums to convert your list of counts into index pairs:
q)(0,sums[countOfIndexPairs]) _ rowsOfDataIndexes

